# Unable to reconnect to socket after timeout

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, frontend

I have this code as a service in my angular app:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

export class AppChatService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:3000';
    private socket;    



    constructor() {

        this.socket = io.connect( this.url);

    this.socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connection established');


   });

    this.socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('reached on disconnect function');
        this.socket.socket.connect();
    }); 



  }



    public disconnectManually(){
        this.socket.disconnect();
        console.log('disconnected manually');
    }


    public sendMessage(message) {
        this.socket.emit('new-message', message);
    }
    public connectToChatroom(roomObject){

        this.socket.emit('create',roomObject);
    }

    public getMessages = () => {
        return Observable.create((observer) => {
            this.socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
                console.log('reached get messages observable app chat service');

                observer.next(message);
            });


        });
    }

}
```

when i try to disconnect manually, the 'on disconnect' function gets successfully called and i can see 'reached on disconnect function' in console as expected. But this statement :
`this.socket.socket.connect();`

triggers this error in the browser:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'socket' of undefined`

and I'm unable to understand why. Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using the `function` keyword, this changes the `this` context, use an arrow function instead:

```
this.socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('reached on disconnect function');
    this.socket.connect();
});
```

You can also look into the `Manager` option from socket.io, to have it auto reconnect

Comment: Tried it and I'm getting this error now:   Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined

Comment: @BlackJack are you sure it's not just `this.socket.connect()`? Seems a bit weird, socket.socket